# How to reduce the no. of for loops in python code

Tags: python-3.x, csv, for-loop

I want to generate a csv file which has rows in the following format
no. of columns is dynamic it may change with value of variable "n". So, if we have n=3 there will be 3 columns:
the first row is initialized with 1/3 value in each cell of the first row as below
0.333  0.333  0.333
similary if n=6, there will be 6 columns and first row is initialized with 1/6  value in each cell of first row.
0.166667    0.166667    0.166667    0.166667    0.166667    0.166667

The sum of all elements in evry row must be equal to 1.

There is no limitation on no. of rows. we are only worried about the sum of elements should be equal to 1.
The following table is set of first few rows of my csv file that has been generated with my code:

0.166667    0.166667    0.166667    0.166667    0.166667    0.166667
0   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0.166667    0.833333
0   0   0   0   0.333333    0.666667
0   0   0   0   0.5 0.5
0   0   0   0   0.666667    0.333333

I am new to programming and i think my logic is not efficient. I am tryinmg to figure out a way to reduce the no of for loops i have used in the below code. if the value of n increases, the no. of for loops will also increase if we follow my logic. Please help me.

```
import csv
n = 6 #This variable is controlled by other factors and may change
f = [0, 1]

for i in range(1, n):
    j = float(i) / float(n)
    f.append(j)

# Generate WS
initial = float(1) / float(n)
w = []
for i in range(n):
    w.append(initial)
ws = [w]
for i in f:
    for j in f:
        for k in f:
            for l in f:
                for m in f:
                    for o in f:
                        if (i + j + k + l + m + o == 1):
                            w = [i, j, k, l, m, o]
                            ws.append(w)
with open('weight.csv', 'w') as cfile:
    cwrite = csv.writer(cfile)
    cwrite.writerows(ws)
```

Expected csv:

0.166666667 0.166666667 0.166666667 0.166666667 0.166666667 0.166666667

0   0   0   0   0   1

0   0   0   0   1   0

0   0   0   0   0.166666667 0.833333333

0   0   0   0   0.333333333 0.666666667

0   0   0   0   0.5 0.5

0   0   0   0   0.666666667 0.333333333

0   0   0   0   0.833333333 0.166666667

0   0   0   1   0   0

0   0   0   0.166666667 0   0.833333333

and so on.. there are many rows, but showing the first few rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

n = 6 # or whatever number >= 1

for I in product(*[f] * n):
    if sum(I) == 1:
        ws.append(list(I))
```

You can then extract your `i, j, k, ...` by indexing `I`, so `i` is `I[0]`, `j` is `I[1]`, ...etc.

Comment: the variable n changes all the time its not a constant 6. So, is there a way to cut on the i,j,kl,.... for loops ? if n is 7 there should be another loop if its 8, there should be 8 loops so on

Comment: @shehnaz I just edited my answer to support any number `n`.

Comment: Thank you socmuch. Now, how would the below lines change. Really appreciate your time and help.
if (i + j + k + l + m + o == 1):
         w = [i, j, k, l, m, o]

Comment: I got this. Thanks alot. You are awesome

Comment: It is massively wasteful and inefficient to use `product` to produce all the possible combinations only to throw away the vast majority of them that don't sum up to 1. Use brute-force approaches only as a very last resort.

Comment: @blhsing You're absolutely right, when I first answered this I only considered the nested for loops problem and didn't really check the code inside.

Comment: Also, you're unconditionally appending `w` to `ws`, which results in the wrong output.

Comment: Demo of the efficiency differences (with the aforementioned bug fixed for you): https://repl.it/repls/InnocentPrudentProjects

Comment: @blhsing Where Am I _unconditionally appending `w` to `ws`_?

Comment: You're unconditionally appending `w` to `ws` with `ws.append(w)`.

Comment: @blhsing I don't even have `ws.append(w)` in my code.

Comment: Ah, I did not reload the page and missed your last edit, where you fixed the bug of the unconditional `ws.append(w)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` over a `range` of `n` to produce all the combinations of indices in which to add `1 / n` into for every valid row, then `map` it to `collections.Counter` to sum up all the `1 / n`s at each index, and then use a nested list comprehension over a `range` of `n` to slot the sums into respective indices:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from collections import Counter
n = 3
[[c[i] / n for i in range(n)] for c in map(Counter, combinations_with_replacement(range(n), n))]
```

This returns:

```
[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.0],
 [0.6666666666666666, 0.0, 0.3333333333333333],
 [0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666, 0.0],
 [0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333],
 [0.3333333333333333, 0.0, 0.6666666666666666],
 [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333],
 [0.0, 0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666],
 [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```